# replace/manipulate "hostname" in url without redirecting to it

Tags: javascript, penetration-testing

Is there any way where I can replace the hostname in url but I do not want the browser to load/redirect/open the replaced hostname, it should just show it above in address bar nothing to do with it.

Scenario:

I am testing a website (legally) where I found that it is just checking the `top.location.hostname` in URL and if it is equal to `self.location.hostname` then it behaves normally else it throws the alert which is why I am guessing there could be a possibility of clickjacking if I can replace the hostname in address bar

If it can be done through JS then its awesome, i can load the my script of changing the name before the iframe domain hits it

Comment: Not the hostname. [History.replaceState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState) can be used to change the path of the URL, but not the origin for security reasons.

Comment: thats what I need to know... website has no CORS policies enabled so there is no issue from server end but on client side there should be something

Answer (score 0):

Double-framing was one of the first attacks against frame-busting JavaScript. This is always very subjective to the exact code used, but you should check here if any attacks are relevant.

https://owasp.org/www-pdf-archive//OWASP_AppSec_Research_2010_Busting_Frame_Busting_by_Rydstedt.pdf

If this is a professional engagement, I would raise the issue regardless of whether or not you can produce a bypass of the frame-buster. `X-Frame-Options` is the strongest Clickjacking mitigation, and would never rely on JavaScript to do so.